# centos7 pam_authz_search for *.group.company.com

Tags: centos, ldap, pam

Upgrading from Centos6 where we were using `ldap.conf` entry "`pam_check_host_attr=yes`" previously, with wildcard `host` attribute in ldap where the host attribute looked like `host=*.group.company.com` providing access to all servers with the domain name `group.company.com` regardless of hostname.

Trying to replicate this feature in `nss-pam-ldap` in centos7, and after several permutations of the below still not working (based on http://arthurdejong.org/nss-pam-ldapd/nslcd.conf.5 and looking at the code where `$domain` is not a valid variable, but `$dn` might be):

```
pam_authz_search (&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=$username)(host=\\*.$dn))
```

Any debug tips or examples if someone has figured this out?

```
Error during login:  LDAP authorisation check failed
```

Comment: notes to date: Need to restart box when changing nslcd.conf, no specific service to restart as it is used by libraries.  No extra spaces in the searchstring.  ldapsearch -x "(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=myname)(host=\\*.group.company.com))"   returns expected values.  hostname -d returns not known, but resolv.conf has entry 'search group.company.com'.

Comment: modified hosts file so hostname -d returns 'group.comany.com'.  But still not functional.